# how to update/create has_one associated data efficiently in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Hi i am learning rails and i got the situation where i have to update or create the data for has_one associated model/table.

**I tried this**

Worker.rb

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :worker_encrypted_info
end
```

worker_encrypted_info.rb

```
class WorkerEncryptedInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :worker
end
```

workers_controller.rb

```
def update_personal_info
   if @worker.update(update_personal_info_params)
     @worker.create_worker_encrypted_info(sin: params[:worker_encrypted_info][:sin])
   end
end
```

now what

```
@worker.create_worker_encrypted_info(sin: params[:worker_encrypted_info][:sin])
```

is doing is first updating worker_encrypted_info record with worker_id: nil and then creating new record for same worker_id instead of updating the old one.
which is not very great ofcourse because i dont need that worker_id: nil record in my database at all.
why do i need to delete that previous one manually with .destroy code?
is there any Efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that this works

```
def update_personal_info
  return unless @worker.update(update_personal_info_params)

  if @worker.worker_encrypted_info  
    @worker.worker_encrypted_info.update(sin: params[:worker_encrypted_info][:sin])
  else
    @worker.create_worker_encrypted_info(sin: params[:worker_encrypted_info][:sin])
  end
end
```

Comment: what if it is not available? 
@worker.worker_encrypted_info would give nil

Comment: if it is present then it should update and if not then it should create

Comment: that's not much efficient way to do that, i already tried @spickermann

Comment: @PrateekVyas Can you explain why you think it is not efficient? There is only one reading and one writing operation to the database. Or do you prefer less code? Then I suggest looking into [Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: yes i applied nested_attributes stuff now already.